# trying to run gorm and sqlite driver but there is a mingw error

Tags: go, go-gorm

I installed the gorm and the sqlite driver.

```bash
go get -u gorm.io/gorm
go get -u gorm.io/driver/sqlite
```

and this is the code setup :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Product struct {
    gorm.Model
    id    uint
    code  string
    Price int
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    fmt.Println("database created ...")
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect database ...")
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Product())
}
```

and this error showed, I don't know what are the required setups to get the code run succesfully but I think it's something regarding mingw :

```
# oop
C:\Program Files (x86)\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: build like `CGO_ENABLED=1 go build  -o ${your program}`.

Comment: @spike014 I solved it when I installed the C mingw64 library instead of mingw.